# Information on a mobile game bot used with discord bot [Updated]

Tags: javascript, mobile, discord, bots

I have made a discord bot using discord.js, discord.js-commando, and MongoDB everything works how I want to however I want to add a new idea to the discord bot.

I would like to start a new project where members can post X: coordinate, Y: coordinate, and the title they need from a mobile game in a discord channel and then it will run the python script to give the title at the location.

For Example:

> My coordinates and the title I need:
>
> X: 748 Y: 614 duke

Right now in the python script I just have the position of each title, If they are detected then it will click the title.

But what I need to do is find the best way to get the user's message like the above coordinates and title, once I get that user's message I will then need to run the python script to grant the title to the user. Then I need to wait 5 minutes before moving to the next person. I know how to run the python script with node.js.

I would just like a little bit of help on finding the best solution to getting the user's request (from a discord channel) then running the python script and then waiting 5 minutes before moving to the next request.

I think as well within the python script I can make it so it will click and enter the coordinates and then search for the location, once it gets there it will click the city and apply the title.

The main thing I am struggling with is Discord.js part which is collecting the message from the users to then allow the script to run.

Thank you,

I hope this makes sense. If not then please ask for more information below and I will try is give you more context/information.

UKzs

Comment: Totally depends on the mobile game

Comment: Rise of Kingdoms is the game, I have seen some websites and applications that work for farming resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used discordjs-commando, but I have used discordjs and I would approach a command cooldown by setting a global variable with the most recent time the command was executed at.

```javascript
var cooldown=new Date();

// Note: no restrictions set on if it's a command or not
client.on("message",msg=>{
  // if difference between now & last exec is less than 5 minutes, ignore
  if((new Date().getTime()-cooldown.getTime())<=(5*60*1000)) {
    msg.channel.send(":x: I'm on cooldown, try again later");
    return;
  }

  // set cooldown to now
  cooldown=new Date();

  // execute python script
  
  msg.channel.send(msg.author.toString()+", you've been given your title");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about the part that "collects locations from coordinates in a mobila game", but assuming you can already do that, then you might find luck adding a 5-minute cooldown with https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/adding-features.html#cooldowns .